# Parse a string and load into DataFrame

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have this format of string 
[{Product:”A”,price:”1.0”,amount:”200”},{Product:”B”,price:”1.5”,amount:”100”},{Product:”C”,price:”3.0”,amount:”300"}]

How can I load it into a DataFrame?

Thank you very much!

Comment: pandas.read_json()

Comment: I used the same way but got below error
ValueError: Expected object or value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [`pandas.read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_json('[{"Product": "A", "price": "1.0", "amount": "200"}, {"Product": "B", "price": 1.5, "amount": 100}, {"Product": "C", "price": 3.0, "amount": 300}]')
Product  amount  price
0       A     200    1.0
1       B     100    1.5
2       C     300    3.0
```

Note the changes in the JSON...

Technically invalid JSON:

- All string-type keys should have double quotes, e.g. Product --> "Product"
- NB: A source of confusion because node.js (and others) will accept bare keys.

You probably want numeric types instead of strings:

- "1.0" --> 1.0 (float)
- "200" --> 200 (int)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any quick way to add double quotes to those keys?

Comment: Assuming you're dealing with a file, standard search/replace in your favorite editor.

Comment: e.g. vim `%s/Product/"Product"/g`

Comment: I tried this, works but not looks good. :)
data = data.replace("{", "{\"")
data = data.replace("\", ", "\", \"")
data = data.replace(":", "\":")